# RegEx string formatting in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex

I'm pretty good in RegEx, but there's one thing I can't seem to figure out how it works.

How would one search/replace in NotePad++ and make sure that the output has a fixed length, while the input can be flexible?

For example, doing a regex on this: `23-6-2016` to become: `23-06-2016` (extra 0 for 06, but not if its 12 for example)

Another option is to create this:

`TestString` and `Test` would become
`TestString______________________` (extra spaces.)
`Test____________________________` (extra spaces.)

Of course, the idea here is to do a mass search/replace where the output all has the same length.

Please explain the thought behind it.

EDIT: to give an idea of the data I'm working with, here's an example row that I need to process:

```
12345678    TXT 19700101    0   100 20160624    100 Comment text
12345678    TXT 19700101    100 100,25  20160624    0,25    Comment text
12345678    TXT 19700101    100,25  100,5   20160624    0,25    Comment text
```

Note that these are separated by tabs. The first 0 in the first line should be formatted as 0,00, the 100 as 100,00, but the 12345678 and the dates should not be formatted with ,00 The last 100,5 should be formatted as 100,50

I got around the date stuff, so that is less important right now.

Comment: Impossible in general but this work for 1st example, sans 2-digit year: replace `\b(\d)\b` with `0\1`. Reason is that plain RegEx gives no mean of checking matched length.

Comment: would it perhaps work in 2 searches? adding all extra spaces in first search, and remove them in second again?

Comment: ah yes. i confined myself to single search.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?  In other words, why does this file need to be formatted: a more readable text file (by aligning columns), reading fields into another application (with specific column start positions), exercising understanding of regular expressions?

Comment: I have to merge 2 different formatted CSV files into one before I can import it. By having it the same format I can then identify the duplicates. But that aside, I'm also trying to learn how to do this with RegEx so I can possibly implement things like this in php projects I work on (not this one though)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In respond to:

```
12345678    TXT 19700101    0       100     20160624    100     Comment text
12345678    TXT 19700101    100     100,25  20160624    0,25    Comment text
12345678    TXT 19700101    100,25  100,5   20160624    0,25    Comment text
```

For 4th column:
`^((?:\S+\s+){3}\d+)(\s)` to `\1,0\2`
`^((?:\S+\s+){3}\d+,\d)(\s)` to `\10\2`

For 5th/7th column:
similar to above, just replace `{3}` with `{4}`/`{6}` in the rule respectively

**Explanation**
[image: 1st rule]

The [1st rule](https://regexper.com/#%5E%28%28%3F%3A%5CS%2B%5Cs%2B%29%7B3%7D%5Cd%2B%29%28%5Cs%29) appends `,0` to numbers without `,`. Now all numbers must have `,\d`.

[image: 2nd rule]

The [2nd rule](https://regexper.com/#%5E%28%28%3F%3A%5CS%2B%5Cs%2B%29%7B3%7D%5Cd%2B%2C%5Cd%29%28%5Cs%29) appends a `0` to those with single digit after comma.

As for [`(?:)`:non-capture group](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3512471), the previous columns are already captured as `\1` so additional capturing is unnecessary.

This only pads number to 2 decimal places. To pad an arbitrary amount, use the `pad excessively, then trim` approach.

**Final word?**
In my opinion, plain regex as in notepad++ is inadequate for this task. Some basic scripting like bash or perl would have handled this with much higher readability.

Comment: Would you mind explaining the regex?

Comment: Its still a bit puzzling, but I'm starting to understand it. Linking those rules and the non-capture group are useful, although for SuperUser, it is often frowned upon because if any of these sites go offline, this answer becomes a bit useless. Now, the link to stack exchange could remain, the other two should be images I think. If you alter that, I'll accept this answer as it does it better than the other answer does. In any case you will receive a vote up.

Comment: @LPChip done. btw, should the source links die, there are other regex visualizers, so no worry.

Answer (score 5):

**Section A: Pad to specific length**

To right-pad lines with N characters using regular expressions, add N spaces to the end of the line, then group the first N characters replacing the rest.

**Pass 1: Add padding characters**

Find: `$` Replace: `______________________________`

At the end of the line add 30 spaces. (I used underscores since spaces wouldn't format on the post).

**Pass 2: Trim left 30 characters**

To pad a dash-delimited date at the beginning of a line, match each section accordingly.

Find: `^([[:print:]]{0,30}).*$`  Replace with `\1`

At the beginning of the line, replace a group up to thirty printable characters followed by any remaining characters with the group.

To pick a different line-length, use n-spaces in Pass 1 then replace 30 with the length in Pass 2.

**Section B: Line starting with date**

**Pass 1 (day of month):**

Find what: `^([0-9])-`  Replace with: `0\1-`

Replace the pattern (line starting with a single digit followed by a dash) with the padded zero, the digit, and the dash.

**Pass 2 (month)**:

Find what: `-([0-9])-`  Replace with: `-0\1-`

Replace the pattern (a single digit between two dashes) with a dash, the padded zero, the digit, and the dash.

Comment: Would you mind editing your post and explaining the regex itself? The reason I am asking for this, is for when I have to convert a CSV file into another format so the data can be imported. It is not always the same so notepad++ regex replace is really the way to go. Besides, its also good to understand how it works.

Comment: I know regex very well. I was actually hoping a description along the line of: find only 1 number, and if so add a leading 0 in front of it. This will skip every number that has 2. Of course this does mean that it will only work if the date starts at the beginning of the line, and won't work if the date is located somewhere else. I still miss how one would work with the TestString to replace it with a fixed length. And your other thoughts are not helping in this case. If you (or anyone else) can write a proper answer that includes the TestString, I will accept it.

Comment: I edited the answer.  Section A will trim or expand any line to a specific number of characters.  Section B will expand the a line starting with a date.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. How would I go about if this text has items in front and after, for example, separated by a \t character? So I want to make `other stuff \tMyString\t more stuff` to be `other stuff \tMyString_____________\t more stuff`? Thats the scenario I'm in basically.

Comment: I still need help with this. Your examples consider that the data starts at the beginning of the row and ends at the end. This is not the case for me which means that none of the regex are working. They're part of a CSV containing other data and I carefully have to skip the other data. This makes that its not working... :(

Comment: I want to thank you for your help. I'll vote up the answer, but I can't accept it because as you explain it, it is not really practical to use in an every-day situation.